# Write digital signature in all .pdf files

Tags: c#, pdf

All the time I was working with web forms, now I have task to make winForm who will read all .pdf files in one folder and implement to him a digital signature.I have that digital signature with extension .pfx.I have following code, but I don't know how to use it, because I'm really new to this.Please help me!-I appreciate your help. I need all windows form because I don't know how that funkcionate.

```
PdfFileSignature pdfSign = new PdfFileSignature("input.pdf", "output.pdf");

System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 100);

pdfSign.SignatureAppearance = "butterfly.jpg";

PKCS1 signature = new PKCS1("test.pfx", "password"); // PKCS#1 or

//PKCS7 signature = new PKCS7("test.pfx", "password"); // PKCS#7 or

//PKCS7Detached signature = new PKCS7Detached("test.pfx", "password"); // PKCS#7 detached

pdfSign.Sign(1, "Signature Reason", "Contact", "Location", true, rect, signature);

//save output PDF file

pdfSign.Save();
```

Comment: have tried that using forms?

Comment: no, i dont know how to use it..

Comment: you have not provided functionality for PdfFileSignature

Comment: and how to do that, what should I write there?

Answer (score 1):

Like conventional handwritten signatures, digital signatures uniquely identify a person or entity signing a document.

How to sign using Adobe® Acrobat® XI is described in the [pdf](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/acrobat/pdfs/adobe-acrobat-xi-esign-pdf-file-tutorial-ue.pdf)

To sign using C# application please refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14488/E-signing-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp).

Comment: I'll try and i'll telll you

Comment: But I need this my c# program do it automatically, not opening this things

Comment: @buba first learn the links and try the code given,i hope you ll understand clearly